# Extend a String class in ES6

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I can write the following in ES5:

```
String.prototype.something=function(){
  return this.split(' ').join('');
};
```

How do I do the same thing in ES6 using the new features?

I know that this is also a valid ES6. I want to know whether there's any other way of implementing such functions in ES6 which is shorter?
The above function is just an example.

Comment: Is the example code your actual use case or are you talking about extending `String.prototype` in general?

Comment: All ES5 code is also valid ES6 code. So you can just use the same code.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I was talking for a general case.

Comment: Might be worth noting that you **can't update to arrow functions** as the value for `this` is provided by their lexical scope.

Comment: It's worth noting that extending native objects like this, while not strictly prohibited, is pretty much never a good idea.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice for more.  (tl;dr: Changes the behavior of the object in subtle and not-so-subtle ways that may break other code.)

Comment: Note that strings are immutable

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In ES6 you can also do it with `Object.assign()` like this:

```
Object.assign(String.prototype, {
    something() {
        return this.split(' ').join();
    }
});
```

You can find more info to the method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Or you could use `defineProperty` (I think that would be better here):

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'something', {
    value() {
        return this.split(' ').join();
    }
});
```

See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

See my comment to see when to use `defineProperty` vs `Object.assign()`.

Comment: What is the difference? What is the advantage? Why would he want to do this anyway instead of using `defineProperty`?

Comment: Yes, you're right defineProperty would be better here. See this [blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/property-definition-assignment.html). Especially the conclusion summarizes it pretty well. I'll add it to my answer in a minute.

Comment: Isn't `defineProperty` ES5 code? I really don't see how ES6 provides a better method of extending `String` than that (apart from subclassing).

Comment: So that means that es5 is still the best method to implement such functions.

Answer (score 9):

Your proposal works fine in ES6, is there something wrong with it?

If you want to actually extend `String`, instead of just adding a method to `String` itself, and get that warm ES6 feeling, you could try:

```
class MyString extends String {
    something() { return this.split(' ').join(''); }
}
```

However, you are going to quickly run into limitations on extending built-in classes. Chances are you will see the dreaded

```
TypeError: String.prototype.toString is not generic
```

error message (this is from babel-node).

Comment: I think this is an issue with babel (which can't be fixed easily AFAIK), in "proper" implementations with real subclassing support this should work properly.

Comment: It works fine in es6 but just wanted to know if any shorter way is available in es6.