# Set the value of the extension of a class with a method

Tags: javascript, string, object

I created an extension of the String object to be able to add some functions.

```
class Text extends String {
// ...
}
```

But I have a problem. **Is it possible to define the value of the character string from methods added in the object ?** (*If it is impossible I do not understand why.*)

If you have an answer (or an explanation for this possible blocking) to my question thank you in advance. (*Sorry if i don't express myself well, i don't speak english*)

Comment: I mostly understand what you're trying to do, but can you give example code you've tried which didn't work as expected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257915/extend-a-string-class-in-es6

Comment: Do you mean `new Text("definition of characters in the instance")`? But no, strings are immutable, you cannot change the string inside an instance.

Comment: You probably know the **substring** method. The mozilla documentation says : ``The substring() method returns the part of the string between the start and end indexes, or to the end of the string.``. 
I want to create a function that does the same thing as substring, for example, but that applies it directly instead of returning it.

Comment: And if I cannot change the string inside an instance, why ?

Comment: @Storm7953 This is indeed not possible with a string subclass. Write a string *wrapper* instead, and you'll be able to set the value that you are wrapping to a different string.